# Matplotlib Fill_Between Two Lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Good Morning, I'm Trying to use Matplotlib to Fill_between two Lines and i'm doing like this:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (16,8));
plt.plot(estudo_df["Sales"], label='Original Data');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat"], color='red', label='Predictions');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat_lower"], color='green', label='Predictions Lower');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat_upper"], color='Blue', label='Predictions Blue');
plt.fill_between(forecast_2018["yhat_lower"],forecast_2018["yhat_upper"] , color='grey', alpha='0.5')
plt.legend();
plt.title('Forecast Sales Prophet - '+sh);
plt.xlabel('Date');
plt.ylabel('Sales');
```

But it is not working...

I use two DS that have the same amount and "index ID", which is a DATE, estudo_df and forecast_2018

Does anyone knows where the error is?

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what is that error? Or, does it produce a plot that is just not what you were expecting... it would help others to help you if you describe the outcome of your code, and how that output is not what you expected.

Comment: I suspect the problem is you are not giving any `x` values to `fill_between`. They are a required input. So maybe `plt.fill_between(x=range(len(forecast_2018["yhat_lower"]), y1=forecast_2018["yhat_lower"], y2=forecast_2018["yhat_upper"], ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code in 2 places:

- pass *forecast_2018.index* as the first parameter of *fill_between*,
- change *alpha* parameter to *float* (you passed a *string*).

I ran your code with one line commented out:

```
plt.figure(figsize = (8, 6));
#plt.plot(estudo_df["Sales"], label='Original Data');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat"], color='red', label='Predictions');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat_lower"], color='green', label='Predictions Lower');
plt.plot(forecast_2018["yhat_upper"], color='blue', label='Predictions Blue');
plt.fill_between(forecast_2018.index, forecast_2018["yhat_lower"],
    forecast_2018["yhat_upper"], color='#DDDDDD', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend();
sh = 'xx'
plt.title('Forecast Sales Prophet - ' + sh)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Sales');
```

and got:

[image]

The index of my DataFrame contains dates but is of *string* type.